# How to report google-maps errors to sentry?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, sentry

I want to track errors that happens in google-maps inside my application.

For example: if there is an authentication problem related to the API key.

By default this type of errors is only shown in the android studio logcat.
And I can't know if the users using my application are having issues accessing the in-app google map.

I want this error to be reported to sentry.

I read the google maps documentation there is no listener for errors.
If google maps doesn't provide a way to track errors or listen for them, Is there a way to make sentry report errors that appears in the logcat?